# How to find and replace value from table that contains more than character in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause

I wanted to know how we can find the data value that has "Hi friend! " (note that it has space in the paragraph- I mean the whole data value contained in the field) to empty data or dot. So it needs to find and extract whole message that starts after "Hi friend! "
For example:

```
UPDATE `person_table` 
SET message = REPLACE(message, 'Hi friend! %', '.') 
WHERE `message` LIKE 'Hi friend! %'
```

Thanks in advance for advice.

Comment: What's the problem with the given query? Anything not working?

Comment: You must replace `'Hi friend! '` only - I doubt that the rest of message starts from percent sign. REPLACE not interprets `%` as a pattern sign, it is interpreted literally.

Comment: Also you may use `SET message = TRIM(LEADING 'Hi friend! ' FROM message)`. This even don't need in WHERE...

Answer (score 0):

> So it needs to find and extract whole message that starts after "Hi friend! ":

That would be:

```
select message from person_table where message like 'Hi friend! %';
```

It is unclear why you would want an `update` statement, since nothing in your question refers to *modifying* the data.

The trailing space before `%` is significant, the `message` must match on it to satisfy the condition.

Whether the string case is taken into consideration or not depends on the character set and collation of the column. By default it is case-insensitive, so something like `'hI FrieND! '` would match.  You can force a case-sensitive comparison with `binary`:

```
where message like binary 'Hi friend! %'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful using `replace()` in this context, because in theory the message could contain the string more than once.  Instead:

```
UPDATE `person_table` 
    SET message = SUBSTR(message, 12)
    WHERE `message` LIKE 'Hi friend! %' ;
```